# Count the number of letters in a small matrix that appear in a Big matrix

Tags: c

C - Void method count how many letters from the small matrix that also appear in the Big matrix **WITHOUT using string.h**

The `Count()` Function needs to count the letters in the small matrix that appear in the large matrix by using POINTERS.

The result should be presented in a new Result matrix.  The Result Matrix will have the same dimensions as the Small Matrix, but each cell will be an integer count representing the number of times that the letter from the Small Matrix appears in the Large Matrix.

I tried used pointer to a specific char in the small matrix.

```
void Count(char mat[ROWS][COLS], char smallMat[SIZE][SIZE]) {
    int i, j;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            const char stringptr = smallMat[i][j];
            if (stringptr == mat[i][j])
                count++;
        }

    }
    return count;
}
```

The count should return main.
This example of the 2 matrices and the new matrix should be

**Big Matrix**

```
P A D A Q E Q B G H R O P H C W S P B Q
M B R P R N V S C H M U J P W C V M F D
V W R K E V I Y K K Q Y N H N G V L B Z
```

**Small Matrix**

```
U N T E
C P G X
D L A B
```

**Result Matrix**

```
1 3 0 2
3 4 2 0 
2 1 2 4
```

Comment: I would first create an array with character counts for the letters in the big matrix.  Then you can go through the second matrix, looking up the counts from your array.

Comment: NO idea :/ How do it... Tried

Comment: Will the Count function only return one count?   It seems like you would want to either call Count one time for each cell in the Small Matrix, returning the count for that cell, OR create a result matrix with the Count function.  However, the Count function is not declared to do either of those.  Can you change the Count() arguments?

Comment: Well, if you're willing to restrict the letters to uppercase, and willing to assume an ANSI character set, then you can create an array `int counts[26]`.  Initialize all entries to zero.  Then iterate over each element of the big matrix.  The array index will be `c - 'A'` where `c` is the character.  So `'A'` gives an index of 0 and `'Z'` gives an index of 25.  Then just do `counts[c - 'A']++;` for each character `c` in the big array.  When finished, `counts` will contain the count of each letter (including the ones that don't appear in the big array, whose counts will be zero).

Comment: Then you're done with the big array.  Move on to the small one.  Iterate over it.  For each letter in the small array, the index is again `c - 'A'`.  The number of times that letter appears in the big array is then `counts[c - 'A']`.

Comment: Yea  Gardener i can change the arguments of method

Comment: It is considered bad form to point people at images of code or images of numbers.  The person helping you would like to copy and paste as much as possible.

Comment: There are 5 "P"s in your example big matrix, but the corresponding position in your example result matrix only shows 4.

Comment: @LinorBenYossef: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

I would break it down into a count function that takes two args:  the letter you are searching for and a pointer to the large matrix.

I would then create a result matrix with the same dimensions as the small matrix and call the count function for each cell of the result matrix, passing in the large matrix, and assigning the result for each count call to each successive cell of the result matrix.

Finally, to make the main() function clear, create a final function that will print a result matrix.  Something like this:

**Edited**:  I have editted the code according to the updates of the OP's question.  This code creates the following output:

```
$> a.out
P A D A Q E Q B G H R O P H C W S P B Q 
M B R P R N V S C H M U J P W C V M F D 
V W R K E V I Y K K Q Y N H N G V L B Z 

U N T E 
C P G X 
D L A B 

1 3 0 2 
3 5 2 0 
2 1 2 4 

The most repetitive char(s) occurred 5 time(s):  P

The least repetitive char(s) occurred 1 time(s):  U L
Process finished with exit code 0
```

The code prints all mins and all max chars for the highest and lowest frequency number.  To do this, it keeps an array of max and mins.  This array need be no longer than the product of the sides of the result matrix.

If no character occurs at least 1 time, then the max and min values will not be printed.

While the OP suggested that I update the Count() function to take care of searching for the most frequent letters, this really becomes complicated, particularly when you have more than one letter occurring the same number of times in the max slot of in the min slot.

So, I wrote a new function that utilizes the ResultMatrix.  The ResultMatrix already contains the frequency counts.  The Small Matrix tells us which letters are most frequent.

So, `PrintMaxesAndMins()` uses the inputs from the ResultMatrix and the SmallMatrix (called Needlestack in my code).

The code could be optimized to find the min and max first before actually gathering the chars that correspond to the min and the chars that correspond to the min.  Rather than do that, my code resets the string of max chars each time it realizes that a higher max has been found.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

const size_t ROWS = 3;
const size_t COLUMNS = 20;
const size_t SMALL_ROWS = 3;
const size_t SMALL_COLUMNS = 4;
const size_t SIZE = 4;

char LargeMatrix[ROWS][COLUMNS] =
    {{'P', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'Q', 'E', 'Q', 'B', 'G', 'H', 'R', 'O', 'P', 'H', 'C',
      'W', 'S', 'P', 'B', 'Q'},
     {'M', 'B', 'R', 'P', 'R', 'N', 'V', 'S', 'C', 'H', 'M', 'U', 'J', 'P', 'W',
      'C', 'V', 'M', 'F', 'D'},
     {'V', 'W', 'R', 'K', 'E', 'V', 'I', 'Y', 'K', 'K', 'Q', 'Y', 'N', 'H', 'N',
      'G', 'V', 'L', 'B', 'Z'},};

char SmallMatrix[SIZE][SIZE] =
    {{'U', 'N', 'T', 'E'}, {'C', 'P', 'G', 'X'}, {'D', 'L', 'A', 'B'}};

void Count(char mat[ROWS][COLUMNS], char c, size_t *count)
{
  size_t counter = 0;  // Initialize the count answer cell
  for (size_t i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
      if (mat[i][j] == c)
        counter++;
    }

  }
  *count = counter;

}

// clear the char array
void zero_char_array(char *array, size_t len)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    array[i] = 0;
}
//
//
void PrintMaxesAndMins(char haystack[ROWS][COLUMNS],
                       char needlestack[SMALL_ROWS][SMALL_COLUMNS],
                       size_t answerStack[SMALL_ROWS][SMALL_COLUMNS],
                       size_t result_rows,
                       size_t result_columns)
{
  char max_char; // char that occurred the most
  char min_char; // char that occurred the least
  size_t max_char_count =
      0;  // best to use unsigned ints when a value should never go negative.
  size_t min_char_count = UINT32_MAX; // Value should not go negative.
  char max_chars[SMALL_COLUMNS * SMALL_ROWS]; // save all possible max chars
  char *next_max_char;
  char min_chars[SMALL_COLUMNS * SMALL_ROWS]; // sall all possible min chars
  char *next_min_char;

  size_t counter = 0;  // Initialize the count answer cell
  for (size_t i = 0; i < result_rows; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < result_columns; j++) {
      if (answerStack[i][j] > max_char_count) {
        max_char_count = answerStack[i][j];  // we have a new max

        zero_char_array(max_chars, SMALL_COLUMNS * SMALL_ROWS);
        next_max_char =
            max_chars;  // We have a new max, reset result char array

        *next_max_char = needlestack[i][j];// grab character from needle stack
        ++next_max_char;  // increment.  Could do in prior line, but try to be clear.
      } else if (answerStack[i][j] >= max_char_count) {
        // we are adding to an old max
        *next_max_char = needlestack[i][j];// grab character from needle stack
        ++next_max_char;  // increment.  Could do in prior line, but try to be clear.
      }
      if (answerStack[i][j] > 0 &&  answerStack[i][j] < min_char_count) {
        min_char_count = answerStack[i][j];  // we have a new min

        zero_char_array(min_chars, SMALL_COLUMNS * SMALL_ROWS);
        next_min_char =
            min_chars;  // We have a new min, reset result char array

        *next_min_char = needlestack[i][j];// grab character from needle stack
        ++next_min_char;  // increment.  Could do in prior line, but try to be clear.
      } else if (answerStack[i][j] > 0 && answerStack[i][j] <= min_char_count) {
        // we are adding to an old max
        *next_min_char = needlestack[i][j];// grab character from needle stack
        ++next_min_char;  // increment.  Could do in prior line, but try to be clear.
      }
    }
  }

  if (max_char_count > 0) {
    printf("The most repetitive char(s) occurred %lu time(s): ", max_char_count);
    next_max_char = max_chars;

    while (*next_max_char)
      printf(" %c", *next_max_char++);
  }
  printf("\n\n");
  if (min_char_count > 0) {
    printf("The least repetitive char(s) occurred %lu time(s): ", min_char_count);

    next_min_char = min_chars;
    while (*next_min_char) {
      printf(" %c", *next_min_char++);
    }
  }

}

// BuildResultMatrix()
// haystack is a pointer to the large matrix.
// needlestack is a pointer to the small matrix.
// answerStack is the result matrix of size_t
void BuildResultMatrix(char haystack[ROWS][COLUMNS],
                       char needlestack[SMALL_ROWS][SMALL_COLUMNS],
                       size_t answerStack[SMALL_ROWS][SMALL_COLUMNS],
                       size_t result_rows,
                       size_t result_columns)
{

  // Loop through the rows and columns of the small matrix
  for (size_t i = 0; i < result_rows; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < result_columns; j++) {
      // Pass the current cell of the small matrix to Count()
      // Count() will then loop through the large matrix, counting
      // the number of cells with the current cell value from the small matrix.
      // Count() will place the final count into the correpsonding cell of the
      // answerStack matrix.
      Count(LargeMatrix, needlestack[i][j], &answerStack[i][j]);
    }
  }
}

void PrintLargeCharMatrix(char (*matrix)[COLUMNS], size_t rows)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
      printf("%c ", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
}
void PrintSmallCharMatrix(char (*matrix)[SMALL_COLUMNS], size_t rows)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < SMALL_COLUMNS; j++) {
      printf("%c ", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
}
void PrintCountMatrix(size_t (*matrix)[SMALL_COLUMNS], size_t rows)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < SMALL_COLUMNS; j++) {
      printf("%lu ", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
  size_t ResultMatrix[SMALL_ROWS][SMALL_COLUMNS];

  PrintLargeCharMatrix(LargeMatrix, ROWS);
  PrintSmallCharMatrix(SmallMatrix, SMALL_ROWS);

  BuildResultMatrix(LargeMatrix,
                    SmallMatrix,
                    ResultMatrix,
                    SMALL_ROWS,
                    SMALL_COLUMNS);

  PrintCountMatrix(ResultMatrix, SMALL_ROWS);

  PrintMaxesAndMins(LargeMatrix,
                    SmallMatrix,
                    ResultMatrix,
                    SMALL_ROWS,
                    SMALL_COLUMNS);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks (: what is u_int32_t? Can I change it to something easier?

Comment: You can call it `unsigned int`.

Comment: I try to avoid `int` when a value should never be negative, but my compiler does not have `uint`.  Instead it has `u_int32_t` and `u_int16_t` and so forth.  I am sure it is a standard someplace.  I should probably just create a typedef for `unsigned int.`

Comment: `#include <stdint.h>`

Comment: Updated to fix a bug in the search function (`[j][j]` should have been `[i][j]`), and to use <stdint.h> and `uint32_t` which is a 32 bit unsigned integer.

Comment: @Gardener My lecture want the function count be void NOT int I tried change it by pointers... But it NOT work any idea?

Comment: @LinorBenYossef:  Sure.  It is easy to just pass a pointer to the cell of the resultMatrix.  I have updated the code and fixed a bug.  The old code used a resultMatrix of char.  However, the result matrix is really a matrix of `uint`.  I have modified it to be a matrix of `uint32_t`.   Fun problem.  Got to run to church.  if you have any questions, I probably won't see them until tomorrow.  Good luck!

Comment: I changed the code now when **run it show only one result and NOT check any char in... You can see it in comment below   @Gardener     How can I fix?

Comment: I am afraid I am off to a meeting right now and may not get to it very soon,.  When is your assignment due?  Do you have a debugger?

Comment: Code is updated with the latest addition to search for mins and maxes of characters.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 approaches to your problem:

- you can write 4 nested loops, counting for each cell in the small matrix the number of times the corresponding letter appears in the large matrix. it will take `SIZE*SIZE*ROWS*COLS` iterations, potentially a long time.
- you can use an array of `int` and count the number of occurrences of each letter in the large matrix in `ROWS*COLS` steps, then compute the result matrix counts by copying the appropriate count from the array for each cell in the small matrix in `SIZE*SIZE` steps.

Here is an example for the second approach:

```c
// assuming 8-bit chars
void Count(char mat[ROWS][COLS], char smallMat[SIZE][SIZE], int result[SIZE][SIZE]) {
    int count[256] = { 0 };
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            count[mat[i][j] & 255]++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            result[i][j] = count[smallMat[i][j] & 255];
    }
}
```

The requirement *by using POINTERS* is uncanny. The function does receive pointers to the argument arrays, I guess you could obfuscate the above code to use the pinter syntax `*(p + i)` in place of the array syntax `p[i]` to fulfil this requirement.  Here is the ugly outcome:

```c
// assuming 8-bit chars
void Count(char mat[ROWS][COLS], char smallMat[SIZE][SIZE], int result[SIZE][SIZE]) {
    int count[256] = { 0 };
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            *(count + (*(*(mat + i) + j) & 255) += 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            *(*(result + i) + j) = *(count + (*(*(smallMat + i) + j) & 255));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are still struggling with which approach to take, a good benchmark to measure against is just the simple brute-force approach. While there are generally multiple ways to put things together, and generally some efficiency gains to be had, the brute-force approach is usually the easiest to understand. That being to simply loop over each char in `small` and then loop over each char in your `big` array and having zeroed `result` simply increment the index in `result` each time the character in `small` matches `big`.

The 4-loop approach takes nothing more than keeping track of which index is currently being compared and which is being incremented. In this case the indexes for `small` and `result` will correspond to one another and you simply use two additional indexes to iterate through `big`, e.g.

```
/* fill result count from chars in arr matching small */
void count (char big[ROW][COL], int row, int col, char (*small)[SIZE],
            int rowsm, int (*result)[SIZE])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsm; i++)             /* for each row in small */
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)          /* for each col in small */
            for (int k = 0; k < row; k++)       /* for each row in big */
                for (int l = 0; l < col; l++)   /* for each col in big */
                    if (small[i][j] == big[k][l])   /* does small == arr? */
                        result[i][j]++;         /* increment result */
}
```

At that point, you have your `result` matrix filled.

The remainder is fairly straight-forward. The only real task left is reading `big` from your input file (or `stdin`). The simple approach here, given the format of `big` is to read each character of input as a character and simply test `isalpha (c)` (or `isupper (c)` if you like). Simply store the alpha-characters, ignoring the rest, but keeping track of the `'\n'` and `EOF` encountered to update/reset the needed counters. Your read could be:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char arr[ROW][COL] = {{0}},                     /* big matrix */
        small[][SIZE]  = {{ 'U', 'N', 'T', 'E' },   /* small matrix */
                          { 'C', 'P', 'G', 'X' },
                          { 'D', 'L', 'A', 'B' }};
    int c = 0,          /* to read chars from file into big mtrx */
        rdx = 0,        /* row index */
        cdx = 0,        /* col index */
        colmax = 0,     /* max col found per-row */
        rowsm = sizeof small / sizeof *small,   /* rows in small */
        result[rowsm][SIZE];    /* result matrix */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    zerovla (rowsm, result);    /* zero elements in result */

    while (c != EOF) {  /* while not end of file */
        /* while index < row and char not '\n' or EOF */
        while (rdx < ROW && (c = fgetc (fp)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
            if (isalpha (c))            /* if it's a letter */
                arr[rdx][cdx++] = c;    /* store it in big */
        if (!cdx && (c == '\n' || c == EOF))    /* if end of line/file */
            break;                              /* break */
        if (!colmax)            /* if colmax not set */
            colmax = cdx;       /* set with no. cols from 1st row */
        if (cdx != colmax) {    /* validate remaining rows have same cols */
            fputs ("error: row with unuequal columns.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        rdx++;      /* increment row index  */
        cdx = 0;    /* reset col index zero */
    }
    ...
```

Putting it altogether you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define ROW  3
#define COL  20
#define SIZE 4

#define CHARSET 62

/* fill result count from chars in arr matching small */
void count (char big[ROW][COL], int row, int col, char (*small)[SIZE],
            int rowsm, int (*result)[SIZE])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsm; i++)             /* for each row in small */
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)          /* for each col in small */
            for (int k = 0; k < row; k++)       /* for each row in big */
                for (int l = 0; l < col; l++)   /* for each col in big */
                    if (small[i][j] == big[k][l])   /* does small == arr? */
                        result[i][j]++;         /* increment result */
}

/* simple zero VLA */
void zerovla (int rowsm, int (*result)[SIZE])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsm; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            result[i][j] = 0;
}

/* print char array */
void prncharray (int row, int col, char (*arr)[col])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            putchar (' ');
            putchar (arr[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}

/* print int array */
void prniarray (int row, int col, int (*arr)[col])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            printf (" %d", arr[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char arr[ROW][COL] = {{0}},                     /* big matrix */
        small[][SIZE]  = {{ 'U', 'N', 'T', 'E' },   /* small matrix */
                          { 'C', 'P', 'G', 'X' },
                          { 'D', 'L', 'A', 'B' }};
    int c = 0,          /* to read chars from file into big mtrx */
        rdx = 0,        /* row index */
        cdx = 0,        /* col index */
        colmax = 0,     /* max col found per-row */
        rowsm = sizeof small / sizeof *small,   /* rows in small */
        result[rowsm][SIZE];    /* result matrix */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    zerovla (rowsm, result);    /* zero elements in result */

    while (c != EOF) {  /* while not end of file */
        /* while index < row and char not '\n' or EOF */
        while (rdx < ROW && (c = fgetc (fp)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
            if (isalpha (c))            /* if it's a letter */
                arr[rdx][cdx++] = c;    /* store it in big */
        if (!cdx && (c == '\n' || c == EOF))    /* if end of line/file */
            break;                              /* break */
        if (!colmax)            /* if colmax not set */
            colmax = cdx;       /* set with no. cols from 1st row */
        if (cdx != colmax) {    /* validate remaining rows have same cols */
            fputs ("error: row with unuequal columns.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        rdx++;      /* increment row index  */
        cdx = 0;    /* reset col index zero */
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    count (arr, rdx, colmax, small, rowsm, result); /* count/fill result */

    puts ("Big Matrix\n");              /* output all matricies */
    prncharray (rdx, colmax, arr);
    puts ("\nSmall Matrix\n");
    prncharray (rowsm, SIZE, small);    
    puts ("\nResult Matrix\n");
    prniarray (rowsm, SIZE, result);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/bigsmallfreq <dat/bigmtrxltrs.txt
Big Matrix

 P A D A Q E Q B G H R O P H C W S P B Q
 M B R P R N V S C H M U J P W C V M F D
 V W R K E V I Y K K Q Y N H N G V L B Z

Small Matrix

 U N T E
 C P G X
 D L A B

Result Matrix

 1 3 0 2
 3 5 2 0
 2 1 2 4
```

Look things over and let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

i want ADD the VOID function *to show user which char in appear the MOST and which appear 0 times ** /:

```
    void Count(const char mat[ROWS][COLS], char c, int *count)
    {
      int i, j;
      int counter = 0; 
      for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
         for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
              if (mat[i][j] == c)
                counter++;
            }
           *count = counter;
  if(counter>max)
      counter=max;
  else
      counter=min;
  }
  if(count==max)
     printf("Most repetitive: %c %d times", c,counter);
  if(count==min)
     printf("Most repetitive: NO COMMON LETTERS (max = 0)");

}
```

It should look like this:
**Most repetitive: NO COMMON LETTERS (max = 0)**
Result matrix:
1 3 0 2
3 4 2 0
2 1 2 4
1 0 3 3
**Most repetitive: P... 4 times**

Comment: You should pass Smallmat[i][j] instead of smallmat[SIZE][SIZE] to count function

Comment: Ein bead ma. Good luck

Comment: I changed the question of function...   I delete it...@sergeyrar  @David C. Ranki

Comment: Thank you. It is OK to copy/paste the output text, just avoid taking a screenshot of it.